# shell - iterating a loop for a (validated) supplied number or range of numbers

Tags: shell, loops, scripting, posix

I need to accept input from user (i.e. 'read').

This input can be either a single positive number or a range of numbers (in the form X-Y ).

I then need to validate this input and perform an iterative loop through the range of numbers (or just once in the case of only X).

examples:

1) User supplies: "8" or "8-"
Loop runs only a single time supplying the number 8

2) User supplies: "13-22"

Loop runs 11 times (13 through 22) referencing the number 13.

3) User supplies: "22-13"

Probably should behave like #2 above...but I'm open to other clean ways to validate the input.

I have worked on the following so far, which isn't very clean, complete, or even 100% correct for what I was asking - but it shows the effort and idea I'm going for:

```
echo "line?"; read -r deleteline
case "$deleteline" in
        ''|*[!0-9\-]*)   echo "not a number";;
        [1-9]|[1-9][0-9]*);;
esac


deleteline_lb=$(echo $deleteline|awk -F "-" '{print $1}')
deleteline_ub=$(echo $deleteline|awk -F "-" '{print $2}')

if [ ! $deleteline_lb = "" ] && [ ! "$deleteline_ub" = "" ]; then
        delete_line_count=1
        delete_line_count=$(expr $deleteline_ub - $deleteline_lb)
        if [ $delete_line_count -le 0 ]; then
                delete_line_count=1
        fi
fi

i=1; while [ $i -le $delete_line_count ]; do
  echo $deleteline_lb $i
  i=$(($i + 1))
done
```

This needs to run in sh, things like `seq` are not supported - so stick with posix compliant methods...

---

To clarify I am looking to do the following (pseudo-code):
1) accept input from user
2) validate if input is in the form "#" or "#-#" (range).
3) Execute chosen (arbitrary) code path based on proper/improper input.
4) If single # is given then store that to variable to perform future operations against.
5) If range is given, store both numbers in variable to be able to perform the operation against the lower # up to the higher number.  More specifically it would be "(higher #) - (lower #) + 1".  So if range were 12-17 then we need to perform operation against 12, 6x.  (17 - 12 + 1).  IOW, 12-17 inclusive.
6) A way to easily denote if data set is range vs single number is also desired so that code path to each can be easily branched.

thanks for helping!

UPDATE:

Using my basic code I reworked it (with a bit of input from a friend), and basically came up with this:

```
            while true;do
                printf "\\delete lines? [e=Exit] ";read -r deleteline
                case "$deleteline" in
                    [Ee])   break;;
                    *)
                    echo "$deleteline" | egrep -q '^[[:digit:]-]*$' 

                    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                       printf "\\n input is not a number.\\n"
                    else
                        delete_range_start=`echo $deleteline|awk -F "-" '{print $1}'` 
                        delete_range_end=`echo $deleteline|awk -F "-" '{print $2}'` 

                        if [ $delete_range_end -lt $delete_range_start ]; then
                            printf "\\n upper range must be higher than lower range.\\n"
                        else
                            if [ "$delete_range_end" = "" ]; then
                                delete_range_end=$delete_range_start
                            elif [ $delete_range_end -gt $lineNumbers ]; then
                                printf "\\Setting range to last entry\\n"
                            fi
                            break
                        fi  
                    fi
                    ;;
                esac

            done

            deleteline=$delete_range_start
            deleteloop=`expr $delete_range_end - $delete_range_start + 1`

            i=1
            while [ $i -le $deleteloop ]; do
                    # Insert all processing code in here
                    i=`expr $i + 1`
            done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a posix compliant awk, try this:

```
echo "$userInput" | awk -F- '
  ($1+0==$1&&$2+0==$2){
     for(i=$1;($1<$2?i<=$2:i>=$2);)
       print ($1<$2?i++:i--);
     next
  }
  $1+0==$1{
    print $1;
    next
  }
  $2+0==$2{
    print $2;
    next
  }
  ($1+0!=$1&&$2+0!=$2){
    exit 1
  }'
```

The script check if the 2 fields (separated with `-`) are numbers. If so, it prints these numbers in an ascending or descending way depending if the first number is greater or lower than the second one.
If only one input, the script just prints it.
If none of the field are number, it exits with a non zero value.

This script could be the validation step of a shell script like this:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "range: "
read -r range
validated_input=$(echo "$range" | awk -F- '($1+0==$1&&$2+0==$2){for(i=$1;($1<$2?i<=$2:i>=$2);)print ($1<$2?i++:i--);next}$1+0==$1{print $1;next}$2+0==$2{print $2;next}($1+0!=$1&&$2+0!=$2){exit 1}')
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Incorrect range" >&2
fi
for i in $validated_input; do
    echo "$i"
done
```

Examples:

```
$ ./test.sh
range: 10-6
10
9
8
7
6
$ ./test.sh
range: 8-
8
$ ./test.sh
range: hello
Incorrect range
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too familiar with awk syntax (though I was able to figure out the meaning of your code).  I have a lot of shell code I need to execute within this loop and I'm not sure doing inside of an awk loop is possible or recommended?  As is I also still need number validation before this loop. Any ideas how I could clean that up AND pull the variables out for use in the larger code?  Your awk statement is cleaner than mine, but without the number validation and the need to work outside the awk loop, I'm not sure what I'm gaining (?).  Appreciate it!

Comment: Thanks, but too many issues with this solution.  First, just as you solved a single number doesn't work (without the "-").  However the big problem is that everything has to be processed in the awk statement.  With the update all that has been done is create a set to iterate through - where what I need is to obtain simply the starting #, x  (the lowest of the supplied range values) and the ending #, y (the higher of the two).  Then perform an operation against that number z times (where z is = y-x + 1).  I thought the example I provided though cludgy was representative.  I'll try to update OP.

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, but I decided to stick closer to my original code as I couldn't see how to process yours outside of simply printing the numbers outside of the awk.  From my updated code perhaps you can now see what my intent was.  I'm sure there is a more efficient way to do some of this, though what I have seems to work and is seemingly easy enough to read/follow.